# How to download video of mp2t format from browser

Tags: download

How can I download mp2t videos from jw player from the website. The video appears to be in bits/fragments?

Comment: There probably is also a playlist file (i.e. `master.m3u8`) file which indexes all the different segments (Discoverable via the network tab in Firefox's developer tools). VLC is able to stream that playlist file, for example. I think the video-downloadhelper extension also parses that playlist file and stitches the segments together.

Answer (score 32):

For me worked:

**In Firefox**

1. Open F12-Tools Firefox
2. Tab Network
3. Refresh Page, start Video
4. Filter: Media
5. First File should be File like: FILE_NAME_XYZ.mp4 **.m3u8**
6. Copy address

**In VLC**

1. Media>Open Network Stream
2. Paste address
3. Choose: Convert
4. Convert as h264+MP3
5. Choose Location
6. Confirm

Comment: Doesn't necessarily have to have .mp4 before .m3u8.

Comment: The file VLC downloads is not playable by any player, but the tip about using the network tab of the F12 tools was super helpful.

Comment: In my case, my web sends the video in multiple fragments, so i have done a python script to download all fragments and then join all the fragments with `ffmpeg` utility.

also be aware that the video has sound , in my case the audio was sent as black video with only audio and the video itself without any audio.

i have joined audio and video with `ffmpeg`.

ask for more details if you want.

Answer (score 8):

You could try this Firefox Add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/

Answer (score 4):

Searching for a way to download web videos in the mp2t format for quite some time, I came across a Firefox plugin (add-on), named "HLS Downloader" (from HTTP Live Streaming), that finally could detect mp2t stream on a page and download it after choosing stream quality (in my case). The downloaded file has a "ts" extension and Media Player Classic plays it without complaining.

Also, there are a few other HLS downloaders in the Firefox add-on list you can try, if you don't want or can't use HLS Downloader.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the firefox browser
2. Go to the web site containing video
3. Press ctrl + shift + E (You are directed to the **network** tab)
4. Select **media** filter and disable other filters
5. Press F5 for refresh web page
6. Click on the video in the web page
7. After load data right click on the one of the *mp2t* **type**
8. Click on the "Open in New Tab"
9. Now show a new window for save file in your computer

Comment: This will only give you one of the segments which probably only 2-3 mb in size. Depending on the media length you'd have to do this step several hundred times.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I was looking for a solution but couldn't find one so I now have a method that will help.

POC url: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7143657191223275521/

Tools:

- Firefox
- WSL (Ubuntu)

Our target is the **Hacker's Christmas Song** Provided by Vicarius on their LinkedIn.

1. Visit the page with Dev tools open in firefox

You will see a place to filter for just media. Enable it.
[Picture of enableing media filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojpI9.png)

2. Download the list of parts.

One of the first few requests is going to be a file that is not a video format. It has a list of all of the parts of the video. Download that.
[Picture of requests and response of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uLmC.png)
3. Download all of the parts.
I used a linux terminal just because that is where I am comfy. I'm sure you can do it in powershell too, I just don't live in Windows.
When I downloaded the file it was randomly named 1703180577056 if you look at the headers of the file it will tell you that it is a m3u file
[File headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmTFc.png)
You can append .m3u to this file and it will play on your windows station. However, I was not happy with the performance so I took it a bit further.

Using this code I downloaded all the parts of the video

```
y=1; for x in $(cat 1703180577056.m3u  | grep http); do curl $x -o vids/$y.mpeg; y=$(($y+1)); done
```

If you look at the headers of the files when they are downloaded individually you would see the mpeg filetype referenced. Hence the reason I appened it here.

1. Concat all of the files together.

This was way simpler than I thought it was going to be.

```
for x in $(ls | sort -g | grep -v concat); do cat $x >> concat/concat.mpeg; done
```

Quite literaly just reading the files out in order and appending them the end of the other one. I'm sure there is a "Cleaner" way to do this but it is functional.

Answer (score -1):

With the Download Helper plugin installed play the video, and when it detects video files to download click the arrow to the right of one of the segments it finds and click on the "info" option. Then just look for a really long string that ends with "mu38". Copy that string to the clipboard, open up VLC and use the "Convert/Save" from File, then use the "Network" tab. Paste the link that you copied into the textbox and click "Save". VLC will then stream the whole file down to your computer