# How to download video from any website

Tags: video, download, blob, youtube-dl

I just wanted to know the general idea to how to download video from any website.

**Thing I try**

- I Inspect the page saw the blob URL in video attribute tag. Copy-paste the blob URL in browser but it can't get open.
- I also  look around the Developer tool in Network tab. There I saw XHR request continue receiving with extension using **.m4s**

  - Copy the above XHR request as curl and create the file using command **curl 'https://......." > file.mp4**. Created file can't be read by player

Can anyone tell me the idea to do this. I don't want to use any library or package like pytube, youtube-dl. Just learning to grab video from any site.

Comment: Related: [How to download video of mp2t format from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266451/how-to-download-video-of-mp2t-format-from-browser)

Answer (score -1):

You can you the following extension’s to download video’s from YouTube . It’s absolutely free.

Chrome : 
[Youtube Download Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-download-assistan/miomdmhicjigcajlcmgcgcocgndkdmdj)

Firefox : [Youtube Downloader Ultimate](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/youtube-downloader-utlimate/)